# Screen flickering and not displaying terminal text properly

Tags: 20.04

I have been experiencing this problem since yesterday, but have been using ubuntu for around 4 months now.
So I was creating some synthetic data, but then my laptop crashed. After I rebooted into my ubuntu partition it suddenly started to behave strange. If I open the terminal, parts of the text is not showing (like there are random black dots projected over the text). Then, after some time, also the screen starts to behave interesting. This can mean big black blocks in front of certain parts of my screen, or just completely messing up the whole screen. I do not experience freezing or completely black screens. Please see the pictures below:

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgUyO.png)

[Screen moving around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcGLn.png)

So, I am wondering, what can it be? I really do not have a clue....

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

I resolved this issue by downgrading Linux kernel to 5.8.0-25-generic.

---

I'm experiencing this problem since today. I think it is maybe related to memory usage and it occurs more when memory is in higher load. But why it is happening now? Maybe some package update caused that.

OS: Ubuntu 20.10
Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic
Graphic: Intel HD Graphics 4600

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment :) I tried it, but it unfortunately did not work for me....